# std::shared_ptr(s) and memory leaks

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

My issue is when i create 2 shared pointers it always says i have a memory leak after runtime.

The deconstructor or for the pointers are called at some point at the end of execution which means they are being destroyed.

However the output window still shows memory leaks.

Is this normal?

Note: I could just a singleton to get around this issue too

(header file)

```
class SRNTY_API Log
{
public:
    inline static std::shared_ptr<sty::Logger>& GetEngineLogger() { return mEngineLogger; }
    inline static std::shared_ptr<sty::Logger>& GetClientLogger() { return mClientLogger; }

private:
    static std::shared_ptr<sty::Logger> mEngineLogger;
    static std::shared_ptr<sty::Logger> mClientLogger;
};
```

(source file)

```
std::shared_ptr<sty::Logger> Log::mEngineLogger = std::make_shared<sty::Logger>();
std::shared_ptr<sty::Logger> Log::mClientLogger = std::make_shared<sty::Logger>();
```

**UPDATE BELOW**

I was asked int he comments of this question how i was checking for memory leaks. I can confirm i am not using `_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF` flag and that i am calling the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` outputting the amount of leaks and also asserting the value should be 0. I will show an example of the code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    // detect memory leaks
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc(0);
    //int mlCount = _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    //wprintf(L"Number of memory Leaks: %d\r\n\r\n", mlCount);
    //assert(mlCount == 0);
#endif

    // run main loop

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // attempted calling it here and still got memory leaks as it must release the shared pointers after it returns
    return 0;
}
```

So i have learned it releases the `std::shared_ptr<T>`'s after completely returning to the os.  But it is still showing false memory leaks after running.

Other things i have tried are:

The `Singleton`, i made a `Singleton` interface i have no issues and no memory leaks. However i'm not against `Singleton`'s but i would prefer to use the c++ std lib's shared pointers as no doubt their better than my `Singleton` solution and also the compiler will be optimized for the std lib not my code.

I have searched for a location to call the `CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` but the way i have structured the code i cannot call it within the Log destructor, not even sure it that would yeild the correct result and not show memory leaks.

(inoncopyable.h)

```
class INonCopyable
{
protected:
    INonCopyable(void) {}
    virtual ~INonCopyable(void) {}
private:
    INonCopyable(const INonCopyable& other) = delete;
    const INonCopyable& operator= (const INonCopyable& other) = delete;
};
```

(isingleton.h)

```
template<typename T>
class ISingleton : public INonCopyable
{
public:
    inline static T& GetInstance() { if (!mInstance) { mInstance = new T(); } return *mInstance; }
    inline static void DestroyInstance() { delete mInstance; mInstance = nullptr; }

private:
    inline static T* mInstance = nullptr;
};
```

The way in which the Log class implemented when using `Singleton` changes to

```
class SRNTY_API EngineLog : public ISingleton<EngineLog>, public sty::Logger
{
};

class SRNTY_API ClientLog : public ISingleton<ClientLog>, public sty::Logger
{
};
```

**Summery:**

No memory leaks when using `Singleton`, can i use it? is it thread safe in c++17? if possible the `std::share_ptr<T>` when and where should i call the `CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` function? Or how should i implement the `std::share_ptr<T>`'s to avoid false memory leaks?

Hope this bumps the question :)

Comment: Please post MCVE, it's hard to advise without knowing what the actual code looks like.

Comment: I'll edit the above

Comment: I edited in a simple version of the code

Comment: What you have above likely only leaks if `sty::Logger leaks` (or if you somewhere keep a copy of one of the sptrs). Need to dig deeper.

Comment: Also make sure that the getters above are not called during static initialization, otherwise it's very easily an UB: across modules you have no guarantees on static init order. I had issues in the past where a sptr was accessed this way - linux-gcc might crash but VS handled fine so far - and I received double dealloc/leak b/c the initially accessed sptr was destructed, not the new one.

Comment: How are you checking for a memory leak, and what does the message say? Some kinds of memory leaks are OK (for example, global variables that get allocated once are OK to have leak). Leaks are bad when they happen continually and memory usage builds up over time

Comment: Your memory leak detector probably reports before your current globals are destroyed.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42 i was thinking that myself. Like i say it does seem to call the deconstructor but after the output window is logging the memory leaks. It's annoying cause it clutters up the output window and i don't know what are real memory leaks and fake memory leaks

Comment: I have updated the question, if anyone call help provide more informaiton, a solution or where i should use the singleton over the share pointer would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just like to provide answer to this question myself.

Firstly thank you to those who commented and provided information.

When using `std::shared_ptr<T>`, the issues is manually calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` what you need to do is use the flag `_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF` which automatically checks for memory leaks right at the end of running.

The code i ended up using is:

```
    // detect memory leaks
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF) | _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF); // added in _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc(0);
#endif
```

Hope this helps those in the future :)